# Getting cannot use import statement outside a module while running npm script

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I am using npm and installed "autoprefixer" package and added this script

```
    "prefix:css":"postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' 
     style/stylesheet.comp.css -o style/style.prefix.css"
```

to the package.json, but when I am trying to run it, I am getting the following error

getting this error
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

Answer (score 0):

import is a keyword not a function so it has a different syntax. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
Use
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');